# removing shared pointers from vector or map

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, stdmap, raw-pointer

I am currently in the process of learning smart pointers and try to avoid using raw pointers.

I have a vector with shared ptrs

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<View>> mChildren;
```

and an Add and Remove method

```
void View::AddChild(std::shared_ptr<View> view) {
    mChildren.push_back(view);
}

void View::RemoveChild(std::shared_ptr<View> view) {
    auto removal = std::remove(mChildren.begin(), mChildren.end(), view);
    mChildren.erase(removal, mChildren.end());
}
```

Now in another part of my code I have a map

```
std::map<std::weak_ptr<ModelGem>,std::unique_ptr<ViewGem>,std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<ModelGem>>> mViews;
```

Now when I try to remove elements from the map like this:

```
for (auto iterator = mViews.begin(); iterator != mViews.end();) 
{
    if (iterator->first.expired()) 
    {
        RemoveChild(iterator->second.get());
        iterator = mViews.erase(iterator);
    }
    else 
    {
        iterator++;
    }
}
```

Now the problem lies here : `iterator->second.get()`
It tells me it cannot convert the rvalue of type pointer to shared ptr.
However if I use raw pointers instead of shared pointers this is not an issue at at all.

So, I am wondering if in this case it would be better to just use raw pointers or can I work around this with shared pointers?

Comment: Does `View::RemoveChild` claim ownership of `view` ?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: So, it should not take smart pointer. Interesting reading: [smart-pointer-parameters/](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/).

Comment: Ok, Thanks Ill read this

Comment: What is the relationship between `ViewGem` and `View`?

Comment: Viewgem inherits from view

Comment: What version of c++ are you using? 11, 14 or 17?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but I think 17

Comment: It is unusual to be storing an object as both a `unique_ptr` and a `shared_ptr`. You can convert a `unique_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` but only by destroying the `unique_ptr`. Who actually owns the `ViewGem` is it `mGems` or `mChildren`? It can't be both. A `unique_ptr` has unique ownership so no-one else should have ownership of the same object.

Comment: I suspect this might be a case of over zealously converting raw points to smart pointers. To be clear, only "owning" raw pointers need to be converted to smart pointers. Non-owning raw pointers are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > So, I am wondering if in this case it would be better to just use raw pointers or can I work around this with shared pointers?

In most cases there is only one right pointer type to use. It is not like one is better than the other. There is only one correct way.

The map holds an `unique_ptr<ViewGem>`. That means it takes complete ownership and is not sharing with any other datastructure. So it is not possible to have the same object in the `vector<shared_ptr...>` without causing undefined behavior. You have to decide which ds has owner ship,

1. If the map has complete ownership, use `unique_ptr` in map and raw ptr in vector
2. If vector has ownership, use `unique_ptr` in vector and raw ptr in map.
3. If the ownership is like both ds owns and the object should be destroyed only when it is removed from both map and vector, then use a `shared_ptr` in both.